# pandas append duplicates as columns

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have a df that looks like this

```
         ID       data1     data2
 index
 1       1        3         4
 2       1        2         5
 3       2        9         3
 4       3        7         2
 5       3        4         7
 6       1        10        12
```

What I'm trying to do is append as columns all the lines that have the same ID, so that I'd get something like this

```
         ID       data2     data3    data4    data5    data6     data7
 index
 1       1        3         4        2        5        10        12        
 3       2        9         3
 4       3        7         2        4        7
```

The problem is that I don't know how many columns I will have to append.
The column. Note that ID is NOT an index but a normal column, but the one that is used to find the duplicates.
I have already tried with `pd.concat()`, but had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count duplicates with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshaping. Then convert `MultiIndex` to `columns` by `map` and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column `ID` from `index`.

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().astype(str)
df = df.set_index(['ID','g']).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   ID  data1_0  data2_0  data1_1  data2_1  data1_2  data2_2
0   1      3.0      4.0      2.0      5.0     10.0     12.0
1   2      9.0      3.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2   3      7.0      2.0      4.0      7.0      NaN      NaN
```

Solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().astype(str)
df = df.pivot(index='ID',columns='g').sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   ID  data1_0  data2_0  data1_1  data2_1  data1_2  data2_2
0   1      3.0      4.0      2.0      5.0     10.0     12.0
1   2      9.0      3.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2   3      7.0      2.0      4.0      7.0      NaN      NaN
```

Another solution with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = df.groupby('ID')['data1','data2']
       .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values, columns=['a','b']))
       .unstack()
       .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   ID  a_0  b_0  a_1  b_1   a_2   b_2
0   1  3.0  4.0  2.0  5.0  10.0  12.0
1   2  9.0  3.0  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
2   3  7.0  2.0  4.0  7.0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: It works almost flawlessly but I have a little problem: The first index (now ID) gets stored as NaN. Can it still be stored with index, and that ID is a normal column?

Comment: Firt column is index, and for column need add `df = df.reset_index()`, `print (df)`. `ID` column contain `NaN` values ?

Comment: Or all values in `ID` are changed to `NaN`s?

Comment: Just checked and found that in two cases, ID contains NaN. That is what probably makes the first contain a NaN. Thanks.

Comment: Yes,I test it, you are right. If then use `reset_index` for column from index, I think it is no problem.